# How to measure pixel to pixel distance of the same object in two different images?

Tags: image, distance, pixel

I have an object in an image and I also have the same object in a second image. A pixel of the first object is represented with different coordinates (pixel) in the second image and I want to know their distance. To simplify the problem: the images have the same size lets say (100x100) and the objects are represented from the same number of pixels. So every pixel of the first image has lets say a doppelganger in the second image. How can I locate this second pixel and find its distance from the first one? Or at least what subject of maths do I need to search into?